# Sitecore Form Designer does not open

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to add an existing Web Form "Tell a Friend" to a placeholder, following this [Article](https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/using_web_forms/creating_web_forms/create_and_insert_a_web_form).
After clicking on Insert in the last step, the Form Designer does not open.
Instead there is the following error in the browser console.

> Loaded unexpected element while trying to get rendering html from
>   server.  Expecting last tag to be closing script marker

In the cshtml file, the placeholder is declared as

```
<div>
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("phForm")
</div>
```

Comment: Try with content editor instead of page editor, select the form item and then click on Form Designer button to open.

Comment: Most likely you have some invalid HTML either in the MVC form templates or your own code. Replace the form templates with the default ones or try with a stripped down layout file.

Comment: I tried with the Content editor too. Same issue. The Form designer doesn't popup. Also, Its a simple layout with header a placeholder & a footer tag. Im trying to load the form in the placeholder